# Messy layout usint TTStyledTextLabel in TTTableViewCell

Tags: iphone, objective-c, three20

This is my first time using Three20 and I am trying to add a TTStyledTextLabel to my TTTableViewCell using the following code:

```
@interface ConvoreCell : TTTableViewCell{
    TTStyledTextLabel * tt_title;
    UITextView * title;
    UILabel * detailed;
}

@property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet UITextView * title;
@property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet UILabel * detailed;
@property (nonatomic, retain) TTStyledTextLabel * tt_title;

@end



- (id)initWithFrame:(CGRect)frame reuseIdentifier:(NSString *)reuseIdentifier {
    if (self == [super initWithFrame:frame reuseIdentifier:reuseIdentifier]) {
        // Initialization code
        tt_title = [[TTStyledTextLabel alloc] init];
        tt_title.font = [UIFont systemFontOfSize:15];
        [self.contentView addSubview:tt_title];
    }
    return self;
}


- (void)layoutSubviews {
    [super layoutSubviews];

    CGRect frame = tt_title.frame;
    frame.size.width = 640;
    frame.size.height = tt_title.text.height;
    frame.origin.x = 45;
    frame.origin.y = 5;
    tt_title.frame = frame;
}


and in my TTTableView I have:

- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    CGFloat titleHeight = [TTStyledText textFromXHTML:[[self.posts objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] message] lineBreaks:YES URLs:YES].height;
    //NSLog(@"HEIGHT IS %f", titleHeight);
    return titleHeight + 20;
}


- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"ConvoreCell";

    ConvoreCell *cell = (ConvoreCell *) [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    if (cell == nil) {
        cell = [[[ConvoreCell alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectZero reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier] autorelease];
    }

 TTImageView * avatar = [[TTImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(cell.frame.origin.x+5, cell.frame.origin.y+5, 40, 40)];
        avatar.urlPath = [[[self.posts objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] creator] img];
        avatar.userInteractionEnabled = YES;
        avatar.tag = indexPath.row;
        [cell addSubview:avatar];


 cell.tt_title.text = [TTStyledText textFromXHTML:[[self.posts objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] message] lineBreaks:YES URLs:YES];
}
```

However, the layout is messy as hell. Why is this?
[image]

Comment: what makes it messy? the last row? why is it empty (no text)?

Comment: that's why it's messy.. there should be a text in there for some reason it's not resizing and everything else after the sixth row doesn't have a text

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I cannot find anything wrong with your code.

Looking at the image, what strikes me is that the last row which is correcly displayed contains a link.

What I suspect is that it could be some bug in `TTStyledText`, which in my experience is not really suitable for displaying full HTML.

Could you try and confirm (or dismiss) this hypothesis? Is always so that a url in a row will make it "go crazy"?

In any case, it will help to set a breakpoint on (or an `NSLog` after) the line

```
 cell.tt_title.text = [TTStyledText textFromXHTML:[[self.posts objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] message] lineBreaks:YES URLs:YES];
```

and check what is going in `cell.tt_title.text`.